# How are the Ubuntu Core rootfs built?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Ubuntu provides "Ubuntu Core" rootfs for a range of architectures however the wiki page (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core) does not provide any information on how these rootfs are generated or what is the 'best' way to do so.

How can I go about generating my own?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure those images are prepared this way, but I would think the way you want to do this is to use the `debootstrap` program, which is the debian tool used to initialize a directory tree to contain the bare minimum set of files/packages to have a usable debian/ubuntu system.  This is the tool used to do a by-hand install from another unix like OS, or to set up a `chroot` or `pbuilder` or other type of image.  Either format a filesystem, mount it, and point `debootstrap` to that location, or create a regular directory that you will later convert to a filesystem image with e.g. `mksquashfs`.  You can `chroot` into the directory and install additional packages after the `debootstrap` if you wish.